# Send cookie with REST-call, please help!

Tags: php, rest, curl

I am developing a website that will be communicating with a REST-protocol. The owner of the REST service wants a cookie to be sent along with the REST call, perhaps via header.

How is this done in PHP, how can I send a cookie along with a REST-call?

Thankful for all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using cURL, take a look at [curl_setopt options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` (storing cookies from a response) and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` (loading cookies before request). It should be sufficient to set both to the same file.

```
$yourfile = '/any/file/you/want';
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $yourfile); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $yourfile); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: So how would a POST request with PHP and CURL with a cookie sen along look like?

Comment: @user339067: added an example

Comment: (just as an aside, if it has cookies, it's not *pure* REST, but that's more of a religious issue than anything else)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify headers using cURL functions.

```
<?php
$submit_url = "https://sitename/process.php";

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");

$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Comment: The cookie was set with a http set-cookie command by the owner of the API after I authorized myself via Facebook Connect apparently. How can I get it to populate the $cookiefile.